# Does the dissociation of serotonin receptors and their ligands really take hours?

Tags: receptor, kinetics

If I understand the principle of neurotransmission correctly, then after binding to a receptor on the postsynaptic side, neurotransmitter molecules must be dissociated from the receptor and removed quickly from the synaptic cleft (see [this book](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK11106/)).

[This article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi981812z?journalCode=bichaw) states that the off-rate $k_{\text{off}}$ for the 5HT<sub>3</sub> receptor and some ligand is approximately $43 * 10^{-6} s^{-1}$. If we ignore the binding process for now and denote by $C$ the complex formed by 5HT<sub>3</sub> and the ligand, we can describe the dissociation process by the following simple differential equation:
$$
\frac{dC}{dt} = -k_{\text{off}} * C 
$$ 
(see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receptor%E2%80%93ligand_kinetics)).
Using the $k_{\text{off}}$ from above, we get that the half time of this dissociation process is $\frac{\ln{2}}{k_{\text{off}}} \approx 16116s \approx 4,5h $. A similar $k_{\text{off}}$ rate for all other kinds of 5HT receptors binding serotonin can be derived from the dissociation constants found in the [K<sub>i</sub> Database](http://kidbdev.med.unc.edu/databases/pdsp.php?knowID=0&kiKey=&recDDRadio=recDDRadio&receptorDD=&receptor=&speciesDD=&species=&sourceDDRadio=sourceDDRadio&sourcesDD=&source=&hotLigandDD=&hotLigand=&testDDRadio=testDDRadio&testLigandDD=608&testLigand=&referenceDD=&reference=&KiGreater=&KiLess=&kiAllRadio=all&doQuery=Submit%20Query).

But wouldn't that mean that, when serotonin is released from the presynaptic axon terminal and the 5HT<sub>3</sub> receptor binds it, not even half of the neurotransmitter molecules are dissociated from the receptor after more than 4 hours? That seems to clearly contradict the statement from the beginning of this post - so is something wrong with my calculations or does it really take that long? Or have I understood something completely wrong about the principle of neurotransmission?

Comment: You're comparing5-hydroxytryptamine to 1,2,3,9-tetrahydro-3-[(5-methyl-1H-imidazol-4-yl)methyl]-9-(3-amino-(N-fluorescien-thiocarbamoyl)-propyl)-4H-carbazol-4-one (in other words, apples to oranges.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That paper is describing the binding between the 5HT3 receptor and some high-affinity ligand, not serotonin.

Numbers of serotonin probably vary according to the precise receptor (species, subunits, etc), but for a ballpark figure [this source](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.ph.57.030195.002311) says 1.7/s, giving half time of ~400 ms. That estimate is based on solution changes, so I'd say it's an upper bound.

Remember from the [other questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52786/can-neurotransmitter-concentrations-in-the-synaptic-cleft-add-up-if-there-are-se) you [have asked](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52795/why-do-sris-help-in-serotonergic-neurotransmission) and I have answered, serotonin is a slower-acting neurotransmitter, and clearance of serotonin is not as fast as for other, faster-acting neurotransmitters. However you are correct that your initial calculation of a ~4-hour dissociation time is unreasonable.